# Is it possible to have a Raycast collide with a particle system in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, particles

I'm making a game, and I'm handling projectile weapons using particle systems. I'd like to be able to shoot a projectile using a hitscan weapon. How can I get a raycast to collide with a particle system?

Comment: Can you clarify what parts of your game are particles? If it's just the projectiles, then usually projectiles don't collide with each other, so you can just do the raycast against the character hurt colliders and environment. If you need a ray to hit a particle, well, you can't do that exactly. Instead, you should describe what's supposed to happen in your game and ask for an efficient way to detect the collisions you need, even if the answer has nothing to do with particles and raycasts.

Comment: @DMGregory The projectiles are particles, but the hitscan guns are raycasts. I want to be able to detect when a projectile (particle) gets shot with a hitscan gun (raycast)

Comment: That won't be possible without creating colliders that you position each physics step to match the particles, or writing a custom ray intersection function that handles your particle system shape. (Or outright replacing the particles with physics objects that behave similarly) Try editing your question to show an example of what the particle systems you want to hit look like, and folks can suggest ways that will work well for that shape/behaviour.